# Converting .results file to .xlsx file with Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to convert a .results file to .xlsx format so that I can read it with Python. If I open the .results file, select "save as", and choose a .xlsx extension, the file can be read in perfectly using

```
from pandas import read_excel
dataframe = read_excel(r"C:\survey\Results.xlsx",'CTsurvey')
```

However, I would like to convert it to .xlsx format programmatically, so I tried this:

```
import os

ResultsFile = r"C:\survey\Results.results"
base = os.path.splitext(ResultsFile)[0]
os.rename(ResultsFile, base + ".xlsx")
```

However, when I try to read in the file, I get an error saying:

```
raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'"hitid"\t'
```

Comment: Renaming is *not* the same as conversion.

Comment: What format is a .results file?

Comment: Oh man, I can't believe I didn't realize that, thanks.

Comment: And I'm not even sure, when I click properties and look at file type is says: RESULTS File (.results)

Comment: Can you open it in a text editor and see what it looks like? It might be a simple format that you can read directly into a DataFrame without having to convert to .xlsx.

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea, it opens in a format that should be usable, thanks